# Unable to pass variables through gitlab bridge to another pipeline

Tags: variables, gitlab-ci, pipeline, multi-project

Here is my simple yaml file

```
image: my/docker/image

stages:
    - print
    - testvarbridge

variables:
    INCOMING_VAR: $ENV_VAR

print_these:
    stage: print
    script:
        - echo $INCOMING_VAR
        - export $INCOMING_VAR

testvarbridge:
    stage: testvarbridge
    variables:
        TEST_VAR: $INCOMING_VAR
    trigger: 
        project: my-project/pipeline-two
        branch: ci-cd
```

the `$ENV_VAR` is a variable in the project for testing... it just says `"this_is_the_variable"`

When I trigger the pipleine..the print stage correctly prints:

```
echo $INCOMING_VAR
this_is_the_variable
```

But when the second pipeline is triggered, it is just set up to do a simple echo command of the variable that is passed in.. it echo's this:

```
echo TEST_VAR
$ENV_VAR
```

As you can see, the when the testvarbridge stage sets up the variable `TEST_VAR,` it is grabbing the `$ENV_VAR` variable up top as a **literal string**. It does not evaluate it and grab the value associated with that variable. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59534578/6309): this will be implemented, possibly for GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)

Answer (score 0):

This was reported 3 years ago in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 1809](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1809): "Use variable inside other variable".

> A workaround is to set vars in a `before_script` instead of `variables`.
> So the example given in the issue would work if written as:
>
> ```
> before_script:
>  - export VAR1="${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
>  - export VAR2="test-${VAR1}"
> ```

Update [February 2020](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1809#note_285156780): [Philippe Charrière](https://gitlab.com/k33g) adds:

> the issue is not closed - the **milestone is 13.0** (for May 2020)

Update [Sept. 2021](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1809#note_667773696),

> One last [validation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1809#note_659699288) is pending and if that's solved then we are shipping this thing in 14.3.

So, soon (14.3, Sept. 2021):

```yaml
this-job-name-123:
  except:
    variables:
    - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /Skip $CI_JOB_NAME/i
  script:
  - echo The job runs unless the commit message contains "Skip this-job-name-123"
```

Comment: Hey, so I tried that and it just ends up empty in pipeline two. Nothing is printed when I echo that variable.

Comment: @MarcusHolden I understand. There is a proposal in progress (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1809#note_225658576), but nothing implemented yet.

Comment: @MarcusHolden GitLab 14.3 (Sept. 2021) should, in a few days, finally deliver on this feature!